# Java/Eclipse: Remove ArrayList element at specified index

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I'm not sure if this is a duplicat or not (it probably is) but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I have a static ArrayList holding objects created from a constructor in that class, or any class extending it:

```
public static ArrayList<Person> PersonList = new ArrayList<>();

public Constructor(....){
  PersonList.add(this);
}
```

Now I'm trying to delete objects from this arraylist by using index, but I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds: Array index out of range:` (index).

Now I know this error is telling me there is no element in the specified position, but then I don't understand why PersonList.size() returns 4 (if there are 4 elements in the list).

I'm new to java, so I hope anyone here can help me. Here's the code:

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(arg0)) {
      try {
        Person.PersonList.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
        list.remove(list.getSelectedIndex());
        }catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Index: " + list.getSelectedIndex());
        updateData();
    }   
  }
});
```

Comment: What index are you trying to access?

Comment: @resueman list is a JList of PersonList, and I'm trying to remove them both in one click of the object. I'm trying to get the index of the user selected JList row and delete the PersonList record of that row. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? `Person.PersonList.remove` or `list.remove`? When you debug the index is it the correct index that you want?

Comment: Yes it is the correct index. And the error is from `Person.Personlist.remove`

Comment: So if you print `Person.PersonList.size`, and `list.getSelectedIndex()` before the `remove` line, the size is 4 and the selected index is 3 or less?

Comment: @Ryan Sayles it seems it works, Eclipse just likes to tell me it doesn't. I'm sorry, I'm new to Java so I didn't know it would throw errors in my face even though it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by this:

```
public Constructor(....){
    PersonList.add(this);
}
```

It looks like every time you create a new object of that class (a Person I'm assuming) you are adding it to a class variable list. I'm assuming that every time you create a new instance of that class, it's resetting the global list. Can you confirm that `PersonList` is not always size = 1? I'm suspecting it is, so move that list to a different class

Comment: Yeah I verified that the size increases (and decreases, thanks). I'll give you the solved, thanks for all the help and useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after testing a little it seems it works just fine after all. It throws an error telling me its out of bounds, but after updating the `.size()` after each deletion, it decreases.

Though I have no clue why it works if it tells me it doesn't?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information given to answer that. Personally I don't think it's a good idea to have a `List` of your `Person` object in that class itself. I would remove that list from the decorator class and keep it in the class you access it

Comment: @Ryan Sayles I'm doing it this way because this is part of an assignment at my university, though I guess that's a good idea.